# change in /etc/network/interfaces results in 2 ip numbers

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I ran Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 server upgrade using a spare ip number (x.x.x.3). When the upgrade finished I changed /etc/network/interfaces back to the correct number (x.x.x.9 see below).

Now  shows the OLD number,  reveals BOTH numbers and the system can be actually reached on both numbers!

I would really like to know what is going on and how to get rid of the old ip number.

```
root@fast:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:fc:e6:d0
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.3  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: blah Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:77037 errors:0 dropped:6525 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12999 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7384634 (7.3 MB)  TX bytes:10674567 (10.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:38225 (38.2 KB)  TX bytes:38225 (38.2 KB)
root@fast:~# ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:fc:e6:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.3/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.9/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 blah scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@fast:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.9
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.254
        mtu 1492
```

Comment: To be clear: have you rebooted?

Comment: No....  The two IP numbers aren't an immediate problem but I'm trying to figure out what is going on. My concern is that the upgrade has resulted in two competing network configurations which may need fixing.